# Exchange 2010 Transport Rule with S/MIME

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010, smime

If we create a transport rule to block all emails sending out with .doc attachment, it seems that the rule won't work on email which is signed with S/MIME cert.

The email sending out is just signed, not encrypted. so I expect that the transport rule should still work on the email. Is there anyway to get around this?

thanks
SC

Comment: what's your detailed rule? please show it to us.

Comment: " Apple rule to messages from 'xxx@xxx.com' and when any attachment file name matches '.docx' send 'DOCX cannot be sent' to sender with '5.7.1' "